# Vimeo Gallery With Jquery - Almost There

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gallery, vimeo

I have a video gallery, using Vimeo, where I have a main player at the top, title, date, description underneath that, with a thumbnail list of other videos at the bottom. I have it working where you click the thumbnail and it updates the url in the main player. The only thing left is to update the title, date and description. Here is what I have so far.

top video, title, date and description html:

```
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/{series_weeks:seriesWkVidId}?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ff9933" id="video-iframe" width="700" height="394" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

<h2 id="wkTitle">{video_title}</h2>
<p id="wkDate" class="date">Date: {series_weeks:seriesWkDate format="%m/%d/%Y"}</p>
<p id="wkDescription">{video_description}</p>
```

The thumbnail section:

```
<a href="#" title="{video_title} - {series_weeks:seriesWkDate format="%m/%d/%Y"}" class="videoThumbnail video-thumbnail" rel="//player.vimeo.com/video/{series_weeks:seriesWkVidId}?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ff9933">
<img src="{video_thumbnail}" alt="{video_title} - {series_weeks:seriesWkDate format="%m/%d/%Y"}" class="img-responsive" />
<span class="playButton"></span>
</a>
```

The jQuery:

```
$(function() {
$('.video-thumbnail').click(function(e) {
    $('#video-iframe').get(0).src = this.getAttribute('rel');;
});
```

});

Could someone give me a hand? Here is the reference page: http://discoverycolorado.dreamhosters.com/series/get-off-your-donkey

You will see that the videos will change when you click the thumbnail, but I also need it to change the title and description.

Thanks

Comment: Where do you get the titles, description etc from?..A database?

Comment: Are you able to change how the thumbnails are coded? Example, use the `data` attribute?

Comment: The title and description are coming from Vimeo through an ExpressionEngine plugin called Antenna. The date is coming through EE.

Comment: I should be able to use a data attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML currently looks like this:

```
<a href="#" title="{video_title} - {series_weeks:seriesWkDate format=" %m/%d/%Y "}" class="videoThumbnail video-thumbnail" rel="//player.vimeo.com/video/{series_weeks:seriesWkVidId}?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ff9933">
    <img src="{video_thumbnail}" alt="{video_title} - {series_weeks:seriesWkDate format=" %m/%d/%Y "}" class="img-responsive" /><span class="playButton"></span>
</a>
```

However, as it seems that you're already hard coding certain parameters for each video in the `a` element, so you could add `data` attributes to hold the title, date, and description of the video:

```
<a data-title="{video_title}" data-date="{series_weeks:seriesWkDate format=" %m/%d/%Y "}" data-description="{video_description}" href="#" title="{video_title} - {series_weeks:seriesWkDate format=" %m/%d/%Y "}" class="videoThumbnail video-thumbnail" rel="//player.vimeo.com/video/{series_weeks:seriesWkVidId}?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ff9933">
    <img src="{video_thumbnail}" alt="{video_title} - {series_weeks:seriesWkDate format=" %m/%d/%Y "}" class="img-responsive" /><span class="playButton"></span>
</a>
```

Basically, you use `data-title`, `data-date`, and `data-description` to hold their respective data inline with the element (I wouldn't do it this way, but since you already have a lot of your data inline, why not).

If you were to take the `data` path, you could then do something like this to populate the fields after clicking on a thumbnail:

```
$(".video-thumbnail").click(function(){
    $("#video-iframe").attr("src", $(this).attr("rel"));
    $("#wkTitle").text($(this).data("title"));
    $("#wkDate").text("Date - " + $(this).data("date"));
    $("#wkDescription").text($(this).data("description")); 
});
```

So ultimately, this approach boils down to populating the `data` fields of the thumbnail element then setting the text of the corresponding HTML elements to the inline data.

I would recommend cleaning up your HTML though, especially since as of now, your `title` attribute has a syntax error because of the `"` within `"`. You could also not use the `data` attribute and rely on the `title` attribute of the thumbnail element, but then you would have to parse the string, split it at the `-`, and that leaves your implementation up to various problems.

Also, this approach may not work depending on how your programmatically inserting the `{}` info into the various attributes.

Comment: Ok, I was able to get the data attributes to populate correctly, but there seems to be a problem in the jquery because it won't change. Right now, I have just the title reading from data-title (I took out the data-description just to eliminate its syntax error from being the problem) just to see if I could get that to change, but it doesn't seem to work correctly. See reference url above.

Comment: What reference URL? Regardless, this is working: http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/La3HA/

Comment: Sorry, here is the url -http://discoverycolorado.dreamhosters.com/series/get-off-your-donkey

Comment: @user1356871 That doesn't help me diagnose your problem. Did you try the jQuery I posted?

Comment: Yes, and it wouldn't change the title, desc, or date. The data attributes are not getting passed to the top video area. I went ahead and set everything back to the way you suggested on the reference page, so you can check it out

Comment: That's because you're putting the `data` attributes on the `img` tag, not the `a` tag. Either change `$(this).data()` to `$(this).find("ing").data()` or put the `data` attributes on the `a` element.

Comment: Ugh, I didn't mean to do that. :) Works perfectly! Thanks